# How to find a specific value inside nested object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I had  a question like if I have an object like

```
let users = {
 {
    name: sam,
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: ram,
    age: 24
  },
  {
    name: jhon,
    age: 23
  },
}
```

How can I access a specific value of an object inside that object( "users")
like I want jhon's age for example

Comment: you can use the `find` method, review the following link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: If you had an object like that you would get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'` error

Comment: @AlonEitan it's also only the first issue here. The next one would be that `sam` is not a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you meant `users` to be an array of objects. In that case, you can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```js
let users = [
 {
    name: "sam",
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: "ram",
    age: 24
  },
  {
    name: "jhon",
    age: 23
  },
];
const {age} = users.find(({name})=>name==="jhon");
console.log(age);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have right now isn't valid Javascript. Add keys to the nested objects and reference them by key:

```js
let users = {
  "sam": {
    name: "sam",
    age: 21
  },
  "ram": {
    name: "ram",
    age: 24
  },
  "jhon": {
    name: "jhon",
    age: 23
  }
};

let jhonAge = users.jhon.age;
```

Answer (score 0):

First your object is not valid

Second you can achieve what you by using nested loops
by looping throw all the object inside the `users` object and testing the name of each object

NOTE: This one to do it. you can do it differently.

```js
let users = {
  "0": { name: "sam", age: 21 },
  "1": { name: "ram", age: 24 },
  "2": { name: "jhon", age: 23 }
 }

for ( let usersKey in users) {
  for (let key in users[usersKey]) {
    if ( key === "name" && users[usersKey][key] === "jhon") {
      console.log("Jhon's age is: " users[usersKey]["age"])
    }
  }
}
```